# Git with VS2015 - New version of program, but keep copy of previous

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I have developed an application using VS2015 and Git for source control (local repository only).

I want to keep a copy of the app as it is and then create a new app based on the old one.  I know I can branch, but isn't the purpose of branching to eventually merge back with the trunk?  I don't want to do that - I want to keep a copy of the original app.

I'm sure I can probably roll back or something in Git, but that's not really desirable either.

Appreciate some guidance on the "correct" way to do what I'm trying to achieve.

Hope this makes sense, let me know if more detail is needed.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can branch, but isn't the purpose of branching to eventually merge back with the trunk? I don't want to do that - I want to keep a copy of the original app.

Not necessarily. You could create a branch and never merge back. Do what you want.

If you are pretty sure you will never modify the initial app,  perhaps use a tag is a better idea (and you will be able to create the 2nd branch once needed), otherwise creating a branch is perfectly fine.